# Handing password by bcrypt. When login method compareSync return boolean false

Tags: javascript, bcrypt

```
const saltRounds = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
var hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(ctx.params.password, saltRounds);
var validPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(hashedPassword, result.password);
```

`result.password` is password, which save in database

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js), you should pass the plain text password as the first parameter to `bcrypt.compareSync()`:

```
const saltRounds = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const plainTextPassword = ctx.params.password;
const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(plainTextPassword, saltRounds);
const valid = bcrypt.compareSync(plainTextPassword, hashedPassword);
```

Comment: In module register, I use bcrypt.hashSync() to store password and in module login I cant use  bcrypt.compareSync() to check password input and password database

Comment: I don't see why not. Other users of that library seem to be able to do it just fine.

Comment: I am storing the hashed password in the database and then trying to compare the password in db with the input password to login but this function is always returning false no matter whatever be the case.

Comment: result.password is password, hashed in database, ctx.params.password is input password to login.

Comment: var validPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(ctx.params.password, result.password); is still return false

Comment: I just executed the exact code I posted, using `'test'` instead of `ctx.param.password`, and it returns true without a problem. Compare the value you're generating and the one you're retrieving from your database.